# How to make a symbol take up no horizontal space?

Tags: html, xml

I am trying to find a way to make a '^' symbol take up no horizontal space in either html or xml. The reason for this is because I am trying to track changes from one version of a document to the next and I want to insert the '^' to show that something has been deleted, but I do not want this to take up any horizontal space in the document. I am hoping for it to look something like this:

[image]

Notice how the '^' type symbol takes up no space in the document... I am looking for something like that to be done, but am not sure how to go about it. Is there any way to make that take up no space in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `^` symbol inside `<pre></pre>` tag.

HTML:

```
My name is <pre>^</pre> Joe.
```

CSS:

```
pre{
  display:inline;
  margin:0 -5px;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z8dqvy6v/1/).

Comment: The problem with this is that it is making the '^' invisible. I still need it to be visible to the user, I just need it to be positioned so that it doesn't affect the flow of the document. With this, if I increase the size of it so that it's visible, it will still take up space and affect the document flow.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you want to be done.

Comment: I basically need it to be just like the picture... where the symbol shows up, but there isn't any change of space in the text of the document.